# Why can we write any integer $n$ in the form $n=2^q(2p+1)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can one show that any non-zero integer $n$ can be written as the form $n=2^q(2p+1)$ such that (p,q) are integers (not necessarily prime).

I really don't know how can start the answer !

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: To show that all integers can be written as the form $n$ sorry for my english welcome for any new edit

Comment: I will edit the question to reflect that.  Check to see that I have retained your meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** Hint **: think about the case when $n$ is odd.
If $n$ is even, divide by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Keep factoring out 2's until you cannot any more- that means that the factor left is odd so can be written in the form 2q+ 1 for some q.

Answer (score 0):

Very easily: let $q$ the greatest power of $2$ which divides $n$. This means $n= 2^qm$; as $q$ is the *greatest* power that has this property, $2$ does *not* divide $m$, in other words, $m=2p+1$ for some $p$.

Comment: What do you mean by the greatest power ?

Comment: Well…  the greatest $q$ such that $2^q$ divides $n$. You divide $n$ by $2$, and the result again by $2$, and so on, until you *can't* divide by $2$.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

Every natural number, n, can be written as

$$n = \prod^{\infty}_{i=1}p_i^{\nu_i}$$

where all but finitely may of the $\nu_i$ are equal to $0$ and $p_i$ is the ith prime number. So $p_1 = 2$ and all of the other $p_i$ are odd numbers. So

$$n 
 = \prod^{\infty}_{i=1}p_i^{\nu_i}
 = 2^{\nu_1}\prod^{\infty}_{i=2}p_i^{\nu_i}
 = 2^{\nu_1}(2x+1)$$